# NSWindow at desktop level in Mission Control

Tags: macos, cocoa, nswindow, mission-control

I am making an application to replace the wallpaper on OS X with an interactive application. When I use hot corners to bring up Mission Control, the application window remains stationary and at the same size (takes up the entire screen). I had to set the collection behavior the following in order to make it show up at all on Mission Control.

```
        [self setCollectionBehavior:(NSWindowCollectionBehaviorCanJoinAllSpaces | NSWindowCollectionBehaviorStationary | NSWindowCollectionBehaviorIgnoresCycle)];
```

How do I make it scale down and center itself in the screen like the normal desktop image does?